# Must free TRegEx object after TRegEx.Create?

Tags: regex, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have seen several Delphi examples of `TRegEx` usage like the following one in Delphi 10.1.2:

```
try
  RegexObj := TRegEx.Create(REGEX_EXTRACTEMAILADDRESSES, [roIgnoreCase]); 
  MatchResults := RegexObj.Match(ThisPageText);
  while MatchResults.Success do
  begin
    slEmailAddressesOnThisPage.Add(MatchResults.Value);
    MatchResults := MatchResults.NextMatch();
  end;
except
  on E: ERegularExpressionError do
  begin
    // Todo: Log Syntax error in the regular expression
  end;
end;
```

So I wonder whether the `TRegEx` object must be explicitly freed after creation in such an example?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Only class objects that derive from `TObject` must be explicitly freed from memory after being created.  `TRegEx` is a `record` instead, so it is released when it goes out of scope.  [`TRegEx.Create`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.RegularExpressions.TRegEx.Create) is a constructor, but not one that creates a new object on the heap, just on the call stack, so there is nothing to free manually (there is no destructor defined for it).

Comment: As others have said in the past, Embarcadero calling such methods  *constructors* (i.e. using the `constructor` keyword for them) is misleading, since there is no *destructor*. I would rather see them call  those methods *initializers* and make them class functions returning a record of the given type. They should stop calling them constructors, as this question once again proves.

Comment: IIRC, there are some records in the RTL that do use static `Create` methods that are not declared with the `constructor` keyword.

Comment: Yes, but that should be the norm, not the exception. They should never have been called *constructor*, IOW that keyword should simply never have been applicable to methods of records at all.

Comment: Naming them Create is a bad idea too. It makes the reader think they are constructors.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!